# NFC - Android device can't read Type 4 NDEF tag content emulated from ACR122U (PN532)

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, acr122, pn532

I'm writing C# application to emulate NFC tag via [ACR122U](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf), which uses [PN532](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/141520.pdf) internally. I want Android to read simple URI NDEF Tag.

I'm able to communicate with Android using [NFC Forum Type 4 Tag protocol](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf), Android detects the tag, but is not able to read the NDEF file - checked with NFC Tools app.

The communication looks like this:

```
tgInitAsTarget:
> FF-00-00-00-27-D4-8C-05-04-00-12-34-56-20-01-FE-05-01-86-04-02-02-03-00-4B-02-4F-49-8A-00-FF-FF-01-01-66-6D-01-01-10-02-00-00-00-00
< D5-8D-08-E0-80-90-00

> FF-00-00-00-02-D4-86 // tgGetData
< D5-87-00-00-A4-04-00-07-D2-76-00-00-85-01-01-00-90-00 // NDEF Tag applcation select
> FF-00-00-00-04-D4-8E-90-00 // optional File Control Information not provided
< D5-87-00-00-A4-00-0C-02-E1-03-90-00 // Capability Container select
> FF-00-00-00-04-D4-8E-90-00 // OK
< D5-87-00-00-B0-00-00-0F-90-00 // ReadBinary data from CC file
> FF-00-00-00-13-D4-8E-00-0F-20-00-FF-00-FF-04-06-E1-04-00-14-00-00-90-00 // CC content as per protocol
< D5-87-00-00-A4-00-0C-02-E1-04-90-00 // NDEF Select command
> FF-00-00-00-04-D4-8E-90-00 // OK
< D5-87-00-00-B0-00-00-02-90-00 // ReadBinary NLEN field from NDEF file
> FF-00-00-00-06-D4-8E-00-12-90-00 // NDEF will have 18 (12h) bytes
< D5-87-00-00-B0-00-02-12-90-00 // ReadBinary NDEF file
> FF-00-00-00-16-D4-8E-00-10-D1-01-0C-55-01-67-6F-6F-67-6C-65-2E-63-6F-6D-2F-90-00 // NDEF content - Well known URI type: google.com/
```

Some helpful tips:

- FF-00-00-00 means pseudo APDU sent to NFC device, every APDU needs to start with it if we want to emulate rather than communicate with actual card
- D5-87-00 is a prefix of output of tgGetData command, each successful response from PN532 starts with this
- D4-8E is PN532 tgSetData command prefix. So each command sent from application in emulation mode should look like: `FF-00-00-00-(length)-D4-8E-...-90-00`
- I excluded tgSetData and tgGetData commands for better readability

It looks like I must be doing something wrong at the very last step of the communication. Is the NDEF file formatted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is indeed in the last message.
Just before that Android was asking for NDEF content from offset 02:
< D5-87-00-00-B0-**00-02**-12-90-00

Last message included the whole NDEF content including the size on first 2 bytes: **00-10**. This must be removed:

> FF-00-00-00-14-D4-8E-D1-01-0C-55-01-67-6F-6F-67-6C-65-2E-63-6F-6D-2F-90-00

This worked and Android open google.com.

Comment: Hi, do you have example code you can share for this?
I'm using the Seeed library but it has some bugs in it for tag emulation and I'd like to fix it as there are a ton of issues open for it.

Comment: Hi, yeah I used it here - https://github.com/JerzyStanislawski/Nandro/blob/main/Nandro/NFC/Device.cs

It works with ACR 122u device - https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/

I don't know the Seeed library, however let me know if you need any help.